# LinkedIn post is redirecting back to company page when clicked

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I tried to share a post to our LinkedIn company page using REST API and the post was shared successfully. But the problem is the when I click the post it is going back to the LinkedIn company page.

Here is the link to the company page:
https://www.linkedin.com/company/10210720

Try clicking any post in the company page and I just found out that it is working on Firefox mobile, previously I was testing it on Google Chrome desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by `space` in the query string values of `submitted-url` option,
I replaced `space`s with `_` and it works fine now :)